# Is there any alternative to Eli5?

Tags: eli5

I was trying to calculate the Permutation Importance by using Eli5, however the command, eli5.show_weights does not fetch any image or anything. (tried in python 2.7, 3.7) can you please help.
The code is as below:

## Code Snippet

```
feature_names = [c for c in train_df.columns if train_df[c].dtype in [np.int64]]

X = train_df[feature_names]

X = X.drop('state', axis = 1)

y = train_df['state']

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state = 1)

my_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100,random_state = 1).fit(X_train,y_train)

perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state = 1).fit(X_test,y_test)

**eli5.show_weights(perm, show_feature_values = X_test.columns.tolist())**#This prints nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Sci-kit learn added [permutation importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html#sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance) recently.

This is an alternative.

In regards to your code.  I think the reason you are not seeing anything is because X_test may not have columns as it is a numpy array.  Try printing out that separately to see.

Another option is accessing the permutation importances as attributes of your [fitted model](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/sklearn.html#eli5.sklearn.permutation_importance.PermutationImportance).

You can try that at the end of your code try:

```
##fit the permutation
perm = PermutationImportance(my_model, random_state = 1).fit(X_test,y_test)

##view importances
print(perm.feature_importances_)

## view with xvalues
for feat, imp in zip(X.columns,perm.feature_importances_):
    print("Feature: {}, Importance: {}".format(feat,imp))
```